# Angular ui grid, install and build

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, user-interface, bower

My angular version is 1.4.12

bower.json:

```
{
  "license": "Private",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
  "angular-mocks": "1.3.15"
 },
  "name": "RiskGenDiagnostics",
  "description": "Bower dependencies for RiskGenDiagnostics",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
      "angular": "~1.3.14"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "WebHelp": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/AladdinHelp.css",
        "dist/js/AladdinHelpWithExtras.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "version": "4.1.0",
  "authors": [
    "Sebastian Janisch",
    "Eleanna Skouta",
    "Andrew Cruickshank"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "WEPJS": "0.0.23",
    "aladdin_vi": "1.0.1",
    "WebHelp": "0.0.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.15",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.15",
    "angular-touch": "1.3.15",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.15",
    "angular-route": "1.3.15",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
    "angular": "1.3.15",
    "jquery-ui": "1.11.4",
    "angular-nvd3": "1.0.5",
    "angular-ui": "^0.4.0",
    "highcharts": "4.2.5",
    "highcharts-ng": "0.0.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "angular-ui-grid": "ng-grid#^3.1.1"
  },
  "homepage": "http://www.blackrock.com"
}
```

I've installed angular-ui and ng-grid separately. But those two will not be automatically built onto the web page.

attached an sample web source code.

```
<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-sockjs/socket.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/sockjs/sockjs.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/WEPJS/wep.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/aladdin_vi/dist/aladdin_vi.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/WebHelp/dist/js/AladdinHelpWithExtras.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
```

When install angular-ui-grid:

```
[liewang.SFOWHB5616DE] ➤ bower install angular --save
bower                     invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes
bower angular#*                 cached art://angular/angular#1.4.12
bower angular#*               validate 1.4.12 against art://angular/angular#*
bower angular#~1.2.9            cached art://angular/angular#1.2.9
bower angular#~1.2.9          validate 1.2.9 against art://angular/angular#~1.2.9
bower angular#>=1.3.0           cached art://angular/angular#1.4.12
bower angular#>=1.3.0         validate 1.4.12 against art://angular/angular#>=1.3.0
bower angular#^1.x              cached art://angular/angular#1.4.12
bower angular#^1.x            validate 1.4.12 against art://angular/angular#^1.x
bower angular#^1.0.8            cached art://angular/angular#1.4.12
bower angular#^1.0.8          validate 1.4.12 against art://angular/angular#^1.0.8
bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to install `angular-ui-grid` on windows with  Git Bash command line.

The problem solved when I substituted Git Bash with `Windows'` default CMD which asked to choose suitable version of `angular`. See image bellow.

[image]

Hope this helps.